# Mongoose sub-documents not updating timestamps

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple schema like below.

```
var childSchema = new Schema(
    {
        childName: String,
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);


var parentSchema = new Schema({
    child: [childSchema]
},
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
)
```

When I run below code, parent's `updateAt` changes but not the child's `updateAt`. What am i doing wrong?

```
var query = {};
var setValue = { "child.$[].childName": "Dummy Day" };
var options = { upsert: true, safe: true, multi: true}
var callback = function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        return res.send(err);
    }
    return res.send(result)
}
Parent.update(query, { $set: setValue }, options, callback)
```

Comment: Which version of Mongoose are you using? Check out https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4049 and https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4412

Comment: @chridam i am using 5.3.1, i already refrenced those links you mentioned. Thanks.
But the doc doesnt update as i wanted